# Introduce a condition on a custom resource in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Another Engineer introduced a deploy date parameter into our AMIFInder Custom Resource in the prod stack which means we can no longer update the dev stack without attempting to recreate the EC2 instance.

Is it possible to introduce a condition purely based on the `DeployDate` parameter so I can still use one template for both stacks?

```
FindAmiResource:
    Type: 'Custom::FindAmiFunction'
    Properties:
      ServiceToken:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub 
          - cfn:find-ami:${AWSAccount}:arn
          - {AWSAccount: !FindInMap [AccountIDMap, Accounts, !Ref "AWS::AccountId"]}
      AmiName: 'Corp_w2016_Std-*'
      AmiOwner: '9999999999999'
      DeployDate: !Ref AMIDeployDate
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding what you're asking for. Are you wanting to not supply the `DeployDate` in your dev environment?

Comment: Hi Jason Thats correct

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some information to key off (like a known AccountId or a parameter in the stack) you can create a [condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) that defines the stack as dev. Then you can use the 'Fn::If' function, like this:

```
FindAmiResource:
    Type: 'Custom::FindAmiFunction'
    Properties:
      ServiceToken:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub 
          - cfn:find-ami:${AWSAccount}:arn
          - {AWSAccount: !FindInMap [AccountIDMap, Accounts, !Ref "AWS::AccountId"]}
      AmiName: 'Corp_w2016_Std-*'
      AmiOwner: '9999999999999'
      DeployDate: 
        Fn::If:
          - DevCondition
          - !Ref AWS::NoValue
          - !Ref AMIDeployDate
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately - Still tries to create a new instance in dev but ultimately rolls back because the volume is already attached to the existing instance.

Comment: Yea, I obviously don't know what the custom resource is doing, and what the impact of setting that to nothing (i.e. not setting it) really is. I was just providing a way to do so. I would encourage you to have the person who made the custom resource change how that works.

Comment: Contractor long gone.  The value is used to update the AMI for ASG's but this isn't part of an auto scaling group.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you change that code to not do that if the `DeployDate` is not specified?